# How to use ranges saved to React state - Microsoft Word javascript API?

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, office-js

I am using the Microsoft Word Javascript API.    I have used the .search() function to retrieve an array of ranges and then have saved them to state.definitions in my App.js React component state.  This part works.  When I try to print out the state using console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.definitions)), I see the ranges that I just saved.

In a separate function, I want to retrieve those ranges and highlight them in a new color.  This part does not work.  I don't get any errors, but I don't see any highlight changes in the document.

Interestingly, if I try to highlight the ranges BEFORE saving them to state, it works.  This makes me think that the ranges that I am retrieving from state are not actually the ranges understood by Word.

Any help would be much appreciated.

var flattenedTerms contains an array of range items that were retrieved from Word a few lines above.  This code successfully changes the font

```
          for (var i = 0; i < flattenedTerms.length; i++) {
            console.log('flattenedTerms: ', flattenedTerms[i]);
            flattenedTerms[i].font.color = 'purple';
            flattenedTerms[i].font.highlightColor = 'pink';
            flattenedTerms[i].font.bold = true;
          }

          return context.sync().then(function () {
            return resolve(flattenedTerms);
          })
        })
```

Now the flattenedTerms array, which contains the range items, has been saved to state.definitions using this.setState.  This fails to change the font.  All of the console.logs do print.

```
  highlightDefinedTerms = () => {
    var self = this;
    return Word.run(
      function (context) {
        var definitions = self.state.definitions;
        console.log('Highlighting ', definitions.length, ' terms.');
        for (var i = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {
          console.log('Highlighting definition: ', JSON.stringify(definitions[i]));
          definitions[i].font.color = 'blue';
          definitions[i].font.highlightColor = 'red';
          definitions[i].font.bold = true;
        }
        return context.sync();
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a first parameter to “Word.run” to specify the object whose context you want to resume.

Word.run(self.state.definitions, function(context) ...)

Comment: Michael, thank you for your prompt response.  When I implement the change you described, I get the following error message:  Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: Cannot read property 'ObjectPathType' of undefined
    at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:279508)
    at b.e.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:337656)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:335761.

Comment: To be clear on the above, self.state.definitions was generated previously by multiple range retrievals to a var called var range, and I used a for loop to peel off the range.items[0] - range.items[n] to the definitions variable.  Would greatly appreciate your advice here.

Comment: @Ryan, it's hard to know what is happening with your specific code -- but you can try the following gist, https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/f1f4cd1a4871887c87254f20b86e8340, importing it into Script Lab (see <https://aka.ms/scriptlab/import>).  The code is from my book, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)", which has a whole long section (10.2) devoted to the subject of "Using objects outside the “linear” Excel.run or Word.run flow (e.g.,in a button-click callback, in a setInterval, etc.)"

Comment: Thank you, when I used the code example from the link that you shared it worked.  I was failing to track and untrack the ranges between usages of the ranges.  I was also failing to invoke the range.select() method.  Also, to all others reading this, I highly recommend the book that Michael wrote.