# How to use ranges saved to React state - Microsoft Word javascript API? (follow-up)

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am building a Microsoft Word Add-in with the Word Javascript Api.  I retrieved an array of ranges to rangeArray.  Then I saved each of the items to a definitions array, so now `rangeArray.item[0]` is `definitions[0]`.  Then I saved definitions to state.

Now, I am trying to access those ranges in a new call to `Word.run`.  As recommended in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678505/michael-zlatkovsky-microsoft), I am invoking `Word.run` in the following way:

```
Word.run(self.state.definitions, function(context) ...) {
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: Cannot read property
>   'ObjectPathType' of undefined at new c
>   (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/…) at
>   b.e.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage
>   (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/…) at
>   appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/….

I would greatly appreciate any guidance that you have.

Comment: See my reply at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650272/how-to-use-ranges-saved-to-react-state-microsoft-word-javascript-api/57652328#comment101908632_57652328

Comment: Thank you.  This resolved the issue.